# UWP on Windows 1903 broadFileSystemAccess access denied on Drive D

Tags: wpf, uwp, access-denied

broadFileSystemAccess works as expected when accessing files on Drive C, however, as soon as I try to access files on another Drive, I get access denied

Without broadFileSystemAccess, load a file from the Desktop. Access Denied as expected.
**With** broadFileSystemAccess, load a file from the Desktop. **Access Granted** as expected.
**With** broadFileSystemAccess, load a file from the Drive D. **Access Denied** not expected.

```
Dim file = Await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("D:\TestFile.txt")
```

I should be able to access any drive. My system has 4 drives and a NAS, only Drive C is accessable using broadFileSystemAccess.

What do I need to do to allow my app to access files on other drives; this is the only thing holding me back from porting my WPF apps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It lets me pick up a file from both my C and D drive. I'm using C# rather than VB, but I don't think that would make much difference.

Comment: Language won’t make a difference but I’ll try C# as well. It’s odd that it won’t let me access files on any of the 5 drives I have, or drives mapped to my NAS.

Comment: This issue only occur in the 1903 ? Have you tested in the lower version 1809 or 1803?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to close this. I updated to the latest patch today and it's fixed. The prompt to ask a user to allow the app file system permissions is still broken (e.g. it doesn't prompt still), but the access to files on other drives is now working.

Additional info: I also created new C# and vb.net apps to test the theory and they work as expected, I then went back to the failing project and it's now working - hence me assuming the patch fixed it.

Comment: What do you mean by `updated to the latest patch`. Which patch your are talking about. Could you please explain? I've the same issue and would like to know which patch I need to update and/or have on my system.

Comment: Windows Updates for 1903 - Microsoft fixed the issue with the latest updates. But they still haven't fixed the notify the user/app that they need to consent to its use. To be honest, now that Microsoft have pretty much announced UWP's death, I'm moving to Win32 apps where the issue doesn't exist.

Comment: Issue still present in Windows 11 22H2 (build 22621). Used the folder picker on an exFAT drive, getting access denied errors from a program started with `new Process()`. No issues if I reformat the drive as NTFS. BroadFilesystemAccess does not help.